# Convert a list of strings to unique rgb colors

Tags: python, list

Given this list

```
l = ['A','B','C','A']
```

how can I map it to a list of unique colors, e.g. `['red','blue','green']` without creating manually a dictionary?

The result would be

```
lc = ['red','blue','green','red']
```

Comment: You can create a dictionary : ```d1={'A':'red', 'B':'blue', 'C:'green''}``` and then ```[d1.get(x) for x in lc]```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify that I don't want to create manually a dictionary

Comment: Then how exactly do you want to associate the values? Is first come assigned fine? Or random?

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as the same values in the list are mapped to the same color

Comment: That means you need somehow to save which letter goes to which color. In other words a mapping. In other words a dictionary. If you don't want to manually assign them, you can do it dynamically but you will still need a dict.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map some value, you most likely want to use a dictionary:

```
colours = {"A": "red", "B": "blue", "C": "green"}

lc = [colours[v] for v in l]
```

As a result of which lc has this value:

```
['red', 'blue', 'green', 'red']
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo, actually it clashes with this answer